# go.mod vs GOPATH

Tags: go, go-modules, gopath

I am currently migrating from `GOPATH` to `go.mod`. However, I cannot understand this:

1. I read everywhere that `GOPATH` and `go.mod` does not mix, either this or that
2. but then the go modules use `GOPATH` to download requirements...

So, the go modules approach uses `GOPATH`, which it claims to replace...

As I try to wrap my head around what is going on, my understanding is this:

`GOPATH` was originally a way to manage user projects AND dependencies. The user projects are now managed by the go module system, but the other functionality, the external/remote dependencies are still under `GOPATH` jurisdiction. `GOPATH` essentially became what a virtual env is in `python`, a library-dump.

Consequently, the go directory structure is something like this:

```
$HOME/
$HOME/programming
$HOME/programming/go
$HOME/programming/go/deps <- GOPATH points here
$HOME/programming/go/module1
$HOME/programming/go/module2
```

By setting `GOPATH` to different dirs in the build script, I could have different compile environments. However, as far as I understand, this is not needed, as go modules can handle if different projects in the same module require different versions of the same dependency.

```
$HOME/programming/go/deps1
$HOME/programming/go/deps1/some_lib.1.1
$HOME/programming/go/deps2
$HOME/programming/go/deps1/some_lib.2.2
```

Questions:

If `GOPATH` is the past since 1.11, why is it still fundamental at 1.19?

Is my approach to answer the above question correct, or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: It’s just a convenient path for a default GOMODCACHE and GOBIN. If you cache modules and binaries elsewhere, then it’s not used at all. You don’t use it directly for any development.

Comment: @JimB Oh, I see, so `GOPATH` is not a primary setting anymore, but a fallback to some other values.

Answer (score -1):

I set my GOPATH to ~/gp

```
ls ~/gp/pkg/mod/github.com/a
acomagu/         alecthomas/      andrewarrow/     apparentlymart/  aws/
agext/           alexkohler/      andreyvit/       armon/           aymanbagabas/
agnivade/        alingse/         andybalholm/     ashanbrown/      aymerick/
akamai/          aliyun/          anmitsu/         atotto/
```

And everytime some import statements needs a package, it will end up there. In example above I just hit a[tab] to show a small section of all the stuff in that directory, there is a lot.

When inside a directory with a go.mod file I run:

```
go mod tidy
go build
```

The `tidy` command it great! It will download what is missing or use what you got.